# Validations on onsubmit of a search form in angular4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, angular-validation

I have a form in which there are five fields

street,buildingNo , city,state , zip

i have to do some validations on onsubmit and here is the way i am doing that :

```
searchByCriteria(){
    this.gridOptions.rowData = [];
    this.isValid = true;
    this.queryParam = this.searchForm.value;
    this.errors = [];

    if ((this.errors.length == 0) && (this.queryParam.zip && !isNumeric(this.queryParam.zip))) {
        this.isAnyCriteriaEntered = false;
        this.isValid = false;
        this.errors.push("Zip should be numeric");
        this.hideEnterCriteriaLabel = true;
    }
     if ((this.errors.length == 0) && ((this.queryParam.city
        && this.queryParam.state) || this.queryParam.buildingNo ||
        (this.queryParam.zip && isNumeric(this.queryParam.zip)))) {
        this.isValid = true;
        this.isAnyCriteriaEntered = true;
        this.hideEnterCriteriaLabel = true;
    }
    if ((this.errors.length == 0) && (((this.queryParam.state && !this.queryParam.city)
        || (!this.queryParam.state && this.queryParam.city))
        && !this.queryParam.buildingNo && !this.queryParam.zip)) {
        this.errors.push("Please enter a value for State and City or Postal Code or Building Number");
        this.isValid = false;
        this.isAnyCriteriaEntered = true;
        this.hideEnterCriteriaLabel = true;
    }
    if (!this.queryParam.street && !this.queryParam.city
        && !this.queryParam.state && !this.queryParam.zip
        && !this.queryParam.buildingNo) {
        this.isAnyCriteriaEntered = false;
        this.isValid = false;
        this.hideEnterCriteriaLabel = false;
    }
    if (this.queryParam.street && !this.queryParam.city
        && !this.queryParam.state && !this.queryParam.zip
        && !this.queryParam.buildingNo) {
        this.errors.push("Please enter a value for State and City or Postal Code or Building Number");
        this.isAnyCriteriaEntered = true;
        this.isValid = false;
        this.hideEnterCriteriaLabel = true;
    }
     if (this.isValid) {
        this.searchStatus.beginLoading();
        this.hideEnterCriteriaLabel = true;
        this.propertyService.getAddresses(this.queryParam)
            .subscribe(
            addresses => {
                this.addresses = addresses;
                if (addresses.length > 0) {
                    this.searchSuccess();
                } else {
                    this.errors.push("Zero addresses meet this selection");
                    this.searchFailure();
                }
            },
            error => this.searchStatus.markFailure());
    }   
}
```

`searchByCriteria()` is called on onsubmit of form.

Instead of using errors array and then iterating that array in html code and displaying errors
in a div is there a better way of handling validations on onsubmit in angular4 and displaying errors ?

Comment: Some authors suggest use a variable,e.g. "submited", that becomes true in onsumbmit and show the errors when there are an error and this variable is equals true

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to upgrade to Angular 5?

Angular 5 added the ability to perform validation automatically on change (as it is in Angular 2 through 4), on blur, or on submit.

```
<form [ngFormOptions]="{ updateOn: 'submit' }">
```

Find more information here: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-5-forms-update-9587c3735cd3

Comment: Thanks Deborah for the reply. Application is in angular 4 so not possible to upgrade to angular 5 as it may require lot of changes to migrate it to angular5.

Comment: Any changes from Angular 4 to 5 should be extremely minimal. Check out the upgrade guide to see what changes you'd have: https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/